# insert table1 of col into table2

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables one named 'bb' with col1=bid (int autoincremented) col2=max_amt (decimal)
the other table 'bbc' with col1=bid (int) and col2 = clm(varchar)  What I want is to be able to have my bb.bid = bbc.bid and have my bbc.clm show up next to each other. For example: 
bbc table:

I want:

```
bid  clm

8   333
```

I get:

```
bid       clm             

8                   
           333
```

Query:

```
INSERT INTO [bbc] bid, clm)     
SELECT [bb].bid  
  FROM [bb]  
 WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT bid 
from [bbc]
WHERE [bbc].bid = [bb.bid)
```

any advice???

Comment: what is the structure of your tables

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have 2 records in the bbc table - one has data in the bid column and the other has data in the clm column.  If you want both of the fields to show up in the same record, you can do an insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO bbc (bid, clm)
VALUES (8, '333')
```

Comment: i'm using this statement in a c# application and when I run it comes out with the '8' in the correct row and the clm 333 in the correct column but not lined up with it. I'm using "Preview Data" in my "Data sources" view.

Comment: Can you tell us what the data in the tables looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Get the select doing what you want then just add the insert.  To me it is not very clear what you want.

```
   SELECT [bb].[bid], [bb].[max_amt], [bbc].[clm]   
   FROM [bb] 
   JOIN [bbc]
   on [bb].[bid] = [bbc].[bid]
```